# Is there any reasonably standard notation for the triangular root of x?

Tags: notation, triangular-numbers

The [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) $T_n$ is the total number of objects arranged in a triangle of $n$ rows, i.e. $T_n:=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Then, one might ask for the *triangular root* of a number $x$, as the positive number $n$ (not necessarily an integer) such that $T_n=x$. Clearly, $n=\dfrac{\sqrt{8x+1}-1}{2}$, but:

**Question(s):** Is there any reasonably standard notation for this root? If needed, would perhaps $\sqrt[^\Delta]{x}$ be appropriate?

*It seems like a very simple question, but I couldn't seem to find any. Wikipedia suggests none as far as I can see, and following Wikipedia's reference to Euler's [Elements of Algebra](https://books.google.se/books?id=X8yv0sj4_1YC&pg=PA317&hl=sv&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false) I could not seem to find where they where even defined, but I may have missed it. Also, I am very unfamiliar with number theory, and most searches seem to result in material related to cube or even higher $n$:th roots.*

Comment: Does this function need a special notation?

Comment: I suspect that $T^{-1}_n$ would be preferred notation as it connects clearly with the triangular number $T_n$ and that's actually what you've found.  Square roots don't have a simple closed form formula.

Comment: @YuriyS Perhaps not. I just found myself in the need of one when working on my thesis, as I refer to it occasionally. Hence I had to write something like "Let $t(x)$ be the triangular root of $x$..." and so on. So, it's not that I can not live without it, it's just that I thought that there might be one. But, perhaps it's not that useful after all, and hence why I couldn't find any.

Comment: @postmortes : Yes, I guess that's sufficient of course; probably why there was no such notation to be found as well. I guess then one would write $T^{-1}_x$ in my case.

Comment: I just found a [very non-authoritative source](https://antwerpenhomeschooling.wordpress.com/2020/09/09/triangular-roots/), which at least shows that your $\sqrt[^\Delta]{x}$ idea isn't that far-fetched. Personally, I like it.

Comment: @user3733558 Well, that's what felt most natural at first. But, as is pointed out, since I already use $T_n$, I guess $T^{-1}_x$ would be most appropriate. So, I also like it, possibly because it seems a bit unique and intuitive out of context, but I will of course use what will make most sense in context, which is $T^{-1}_x$.

Answer (score 4):

The OEIS uses $\operatorname{trinv}(x)$ for $\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8x+1}+1}2\right\rfloor$, which differs from your function by $1$; it appears [43 times](https://oeis.org/search?q=trinv&language=english&go=Search) as of this post's writing.